# How to access local host via https?

Tags: https, ngrok

I am trying to connect my localhost server via https and used ngrok for tunnelling to https but i am facing issues in connecting ngrok to localhost server

i have tried connecting on various ports but the local host is not connecting

[Following result shows up on command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIQRR.jpg)